# Rename a column based on the original column's name R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, rename

I have a dataframe that similar to this: (in fact, 16 in a for-loop)

```
head(data)
# A tibble: 1 x 4
    AAA   AAC    AB    AC
1    18    25    39     9
2    20    25    30     7
```

I want to dynamically change all column names based on the column's original names, something like this (I've tried with `str_glue`, but I get an error):

```
### I have a for-loop: (NOT WORKING) (this is a part of the loop)

assign(str_glue("df_{str_sub(data[i], 23, - 5)}"),
           read.delim(data[i], sep = ",", header = T) %>% 
             mutate(ID = Participants,
             str_glue("New_{str_sub(data[i], 23, - 5)}_AAA") = AAA,
             str_glue("New_{str_sub(data[i], 23, - 5)}_AAB") = AAC,
             str_glue("New_{str_sub(data[i], 23, - 5)}_AB") = AB,
             str_glue("New_{str_sub(data[i], 23, - 5)}_AC") = AC)
```

Desired output:

```
### Note:
### depending on the index-i, 
### str_glue("New_{str_sub(data[i], 23, - 5)}_AAA") will get me either 50,100 or 150

### desired output for i = 1 
    New_50_AAA   New_50_AAC    New_50_AB    New_50_AC
1    18    25    39     9
2    20    25    30     7
```

I'm sure that there's an elegant way to do that. I've seen some related posts, but none seemed to help me. Any ideas? Thanks :)

PS: If there's also a way to dynamically repeat the original's column's name without repeating it with str_, that would be perfect, it would save me 4 lines

**EDIT**

The whole loop looks like this:

"data" is a list of 16 .txt files, each one is called "xxxxxxxxx_xx_50.txt", "xxxxxxxxx_xx_100.txt" (so on)

```
for (i in 1:length(data)) {
  
  if (grepl("xxxxxxxxx_x1_.txt$", data[i])) {
    
    assign(str_glue("df_narr{str_sub(data[i], 23, - 5)}"),
           read.delim(data[i], sep = ",", header = T) %>% 
           mutate(ID = Participants,
             str_glue("New_1{str_sub(data[i], 23, - 5)}_AAA") = AAA,
             str_glue("New_1{str_sub(data[i], 23, - 5)}_AAB") = AAC,
             str_glue("New_1{str_sub(data[i], 23, - 5)}_AB") = AB,
             str_glue("New_1{str_sub(data[i], 23, - 5)}_AC") = AC) %>%
             mutate_if(is.numeric, round, digits = 2)) 

} else if (grepl("xxxxxxxxx_x2_.txt$", data[i])) {

assign(str_glue("df_narr{str_sub(data[i], 23, - 5)}"),
           read.delim(data[i], sep = ",", header = T) %>% 
           mutate(ID = Participants,
             str_glue("New_2{str_sub(data[i], 23, - 5)}_AAA") = AAA,
             str_glue("New_2{str_sub(data[i], 23, - 5)}_AAB") = AAC,
             str_glue("New_2{str_sub(data[i], 23, - 5)}_AB") = AB,
             str_glue("New_2{str_sub(data[i], 23, - 5)}_AC") = AC) %>%
             mutate_if(is.numeric, round, digits = 2)) 
  }
}
```

Comment: Isn't this just `names(data) <- paste0("New_50_", names(data))`.  Creating multiple objects in the global env is not recommended.  You could read all those data into a list and rename if needed

Comment: so, @akrun, that could be, but I have 16 dataframes, I'm reading them all in a for-loop, some will have 50, some 150, some 100 and some 200, that's why I cannot "set" 50, it will depend on data[i]

Comment: Are those 50, 150, 200, the number of columns?

Comment: so, no, in fact, these numbers are in the dataframes' names. For example: each data is called: "xxxxxxxxx_xx_50.txt" or "xxxxxxxxx_xx_100.txt" (so on). But all of them share the very same columns names (AAA,AAC, AC,AB), that's why I want to rename each one with the df's number, that's why I've thought of str_glue to extract only  the numbers and glue them to the variable's names

Comment: @akrun , I'll add the whole loop in order to increase the post

Comment: Please try the updated solution in my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to keep the datasets in a `list` and rename them - get the files in the folder with `list.files`, then extract the digits (`\\d+` - one or more digits) before the `.txt` from the files ('nm1'), loop over the files and the names extracted in `Map`, read the data and modify the column names by `paste`ing the 'New_', corresponding digits ('nm') and the original column names

```
files <- list.files(path = 'path/to/your/folder', pattern = "\\.txt$", 
     full.names = TRUE)
nm1 <- sub(".*_(\\d+)\\.txt", "\\1", basename(files))
lst1 <- Map(\(x, nm) {

        tmp <- read.table(x) 
        num_cols <- sapply(tmp, is.numeric)
        tmp[num_cols] <- lapply(tmp[num_cols], round, digits = 2)
        cols_to_rename <- names(tmp) != "Participants"
         names(tmp)[cols_to_rename] <- paste0("New_", nm, "_", 
               names(tmp)[cols_to_rename])
         names(tmp)[!cols_to_rename] <- "ID"
        tmp
    }, files, nm1)
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
lst2 <- imap(setNames(files, nm1), ~ {
      nm <- .y
      read_table(.x) %>%
       rename_with(~ str_c("New_", nm, "_", .x), -Participants) %>%
      mutate(across(where(is.numeric), round, digits = 2)) %>%
      rename(ID = Participants)
    })
```

---

or in a `for` loop

```
# for storing the output from the `for` loop
lst3 <- vector('list', length(files))
# loop over the sequence of files
for(i in seq_along(files)) {
   tmp <- read.table(files[i])
   cols_to_rename <- names(tmp) != "Participants"
    names(tmp)[cols_to_rename] <- paste0("New_", nm1[i], "_", 
               names(tmp)[cols_to_rename]) 
    names(tmp)[!cols_to_rename] <- "ID"
   num_cols <- sapply(tmp, is.numeric)
   tmp[num_cols] <- lapply(tmp[num_cols], round, digits = 2)
   lst3[[i]] <- tmp
  }
```

Comment: this may be a silly question, but since I'm already using a for-loop, is there a way to keep with the index-i ? (I know that is preferable to use map/lapply family to for-loops in R, but I'm still learning them)

Comment: @LarissaCury you can use the for loop, but I would advise to keep it in a list and not `assign`

Comment: @LarissaCury Updated with `for` loop

Comment: I still didn't get it all right, but I'm trying to, thank you. I've just updated the post with the rest of the conditinal part inside the for-loop. All 16 txts share those colluns names which I'm trying to rename, but they also share an "ID" name, which is ok to mantain througout all datasets, is there a way to "skip' this one?

Comment: @LarissaCury is it `Participants` the column common in all datasets you want to skip

Comment: @LarissaCury if that is the case, I updated the post

Comment: thank you, I've used your suggestions!  I've also made a follow-up post on how to dinamically rearrange the collumns afterwards, would you take a look at it ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73941682/how-to-dynamically-intercalate-columns-with-pattern-in-r @akrun

Comment: @LarissaCury try the soluiton in the post.  I took some time to construct the data.  It is better to show input data with `dput` so that it is easier to copy/paste and test