# does R have a "alternate()" function?

Tags: r, regex, dataframe, dplyr, stringr

I have a large df and I'm trying to relocate the columns with patterns instead of manually write each column name in `select()`. More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73941682/how-to-dynamically-intercalate-columns-with-pattern-in-r).

- A glimpse of the issue **(edit)**: All my columns share a pattern `ARG_G1_50_AAA` or `ARG_G2_50_AAA` or `NARR_G1_50_AAA`  or `NARR_G2_50_AAA`. The final parts are: `AAA, AAC, AC and AB`. I need two subsets of this data.

Set 1: I need to intercalate "G1" and "G2" columns (in the order 50, 100, 150 and 200) and in the order (AAA, AAC, AC and AB). Ex:

```
NARR_G1_50_AAA, NARR_G2_50_AAA,
NARR_G1_50_AAC, NARR_G2_50_AAC.... so on
```

Set 2: I need to intercalate "Narr" and "Arg" columns (again, 50 before 100, 150 and 200 and  AAA before AAC, AC and AB). No need to intercalate G1 and G2 now. Ex:

```
NARR_G1_50_AAA, ARG_G1_50_AAA, 
NARR_G2_50_AAA, ARG_G2_50_AAA... so on
```

- Basically, I was able to partially solve my problem *(cf. linked post above)* with:

```
dfPaired <- merged_DF %>%
            dplyr::select(ID, str_subset(names(merged_DF), "G?_50\\w*")) 
  
   head(dfPaired)
       ID ARG_G1_50_AAA ARG_G1_50_AAC ARG_G1_50_AC ARG_G1_50_AB 
          ARG_G2_50_AAA ARG_G2_50_AAC, ARG_G2_50_AC ARG_G2_50_AB....

## I know that I'm only getting the "50" here, in fact I need all, but It wouldn't be "A" problem to repeat the code for 100, 150, 200)
```

- How can I make R "intercalate" the strings? I mean, I need:

```
ARG_G1_50_AAA, ARG_G2_50_AAA 
ARG_G1_50_AAC, ARG_G2_50_AAC, 
ARG_G1_50_AC, ARG_G2_50_AC,
ARG_G1_50_AB, ARG_G2_50_AB ... (so on) 

(intercalate G1 and G2 coluns in case of set 1)
```

**Questions** :

- Could I use sth as `seq(by = 2)` ?
- Is there a way to pass two patterns to `str()` and ask it to intercalate the output?
- Is there an "intercalate()" function that I could pass to `str_subset(names(merged_DF), "G?_50\\w*"))` ?
  ** I mean, sth as int(str_subset(names(merged_DF), "G1_50\w*")), str_subset(names(merged_DF), "G2_50\w*")) Thanks in advance :)

EDIT:

```
dput(merged_DF[1:50])
structure(list(ID = structure(c("P1", "P2", "P3", "P4", "P5", 
"P6", "P7", "P8", "P9", "P10", "P11", "P12", "P13", "P14", "P15", 
"P16", "P17", "P18", "P19", "P20", "P21", "P22", "P23", "P24", 
"P25", "P26", "P27", "P28", "P29", "P30", "P31", "P32", "P33", 
"P34", "P35", "P36", "P37", "P38", "P39", "P40", "P41", "P42", 
"P43", "P44", "P45", "P46", "P47", "P48", "P49", "P50", "P51", 
"P52", "P53", "P54", "P55", "P56", "P57", "P58", "P59", "P60", 
"P61", "P62", "P63", "P64", "P65", "P66", "P67", "P68", "P69", 
"P70", "P71"), class = c("glue", "character")), ARG_G1_100_AAA = c(68.53, 
65.9, 69.78, 68.29, NaN, 69.5, 67.05, 73.74, 73.59, 72.57, 64.33, 
67.79, 72.94, 63.75, 71.56, 75.5, 68.16, NA, 65.64, 68.36, 69.75, 
72.73, 67.67, 66.19, 62.94, 72.48, 72.19, 62.44, 72.5, 71.06, 
70.4, 69.14, NA, 67.59, 69.1, 74.05, NA, 68.6, 68.27, 59.12, 
NA, NA, 63.7, 67.18, NA, 68.38, 63.44, 72.56, 66.06, 66.53, 73.19, 
NA, NA, NA, 73.44, 67.45, 72.91, 65.81, 73.96, 75, 75.89, 72, 
NA, 68.2, 67.29, 69.91, NaN, 69.67, 68.39, 69.2, 67.55), ARG_G1_100_AAC = c(70.18, 
67.65, 71.89, 70.42, NaN, 72.38, 69.67, 75.63, 76.7, 76.21, 66.5, 
70.57, 76.72, 66.4, 74.75, 79.17, 70.84, NA, 67.82, 70, 71.88, 
74.55, 69.33, 69.5, 65.25, 75.05, 75.44, 64.56, 74.88, 74.29, 
72.4, 71.93, NA, 69.12, 71.43, 77.53, NA, 71.93, 70.4, 60.25, 
NA, NA, 64.8, 69, NA, 71.19, 71.12, 75.04, 68.89, 68.26, 75.81, 
NA, NA, NA, 75.89, 68.82, 77.35, 68.38, 76.71, 79.12, 78.89, 
73.5, NA, 69.7, 69.82, 70.91, NaN, 72, 71.17, 71.85, 69.7), ARG_G1_100_AC = c(4.35, 
4.95, 1.44, 2.71, NaN, 3.25, 3.95, 2.26, 0.85, 1.21, 5.33, 5.43, 
0.83, 10.4, 2.56, 0.33, 4.92, NA, 10.55, 3.43, 2.94, 1.55, 5.33, 
6.44, 5.25, 2, 3.12, 8.5, 1.38, 3.76, 1.9, 2.79, NA, 4.06, 5.57, 
1.95, NA, 6.07, 2.67, 7, NA, NA, 8, 4.76, NA, 4.19, 2.68, 3, 
4.94, 4.79, 2.19, NA, NA, NA, 1.78, 5.27, 2.52, 5.88, 1.96, 1.12, 
0.67, 3.28, NA, 3.5, 3.41, 3.73, NaN, 3.83, 6.06, 3.3, 3.9), 
    ARG_G1_100_AB = c(4.94, 6.55, 2.44, 3, NaN, 3.25, 4.71, 2.84, 
    1.07, 2, 5.33, 5.43, 1.72, 10.55, 3, 1.17, 5.8, NA, 10.55, 
    4.21, 2.94, 3.55, 6.33, 8.25, 5.88, 2, 3.44, 9.22, 1.69, 
    4.18, 2.5, 4.71, NA, 4.41, 5.9, 2.21, NA, 6.67, 3.33, 7, 
    NA, NA, 8, 4.76, NA, 4.44, 2.68, 3.16, 4.94, 5.42, 2.81, 
    NA, NA, NA, 1.78, 6.09, 2.52, 6.56, 1.96, 1.12, 0.67, 3.78, 
    NA, 3.5, 3.65, 5.27, NaN, 4.33, 6.78, 3.6, 4.35), ARG_G1_150_AAA = c(93.38, 
    90.2, 98.33, 94.69, NaN, 99, 93.64, 104.22, 104.8, 103.17, 
    87, 93.83, 101.89, 87.5, 100.38, 107, 94.69, NA, 90.75, 91.5, 
    93.88, 99.5, NaN, 89.5, 86.5, 100.55, 101, 84.22, 101.88, 
    94.62, 97.2, 96.5, NA, 87.38, 96.82, 103.67, NA, 97.57, 95.86, 
    84, NA, NA, 85.5, 90.5, NA, 96.29, 89.71, 101.64, 92.33, 
    93.89, 104.43, NA, NA, NA, 101.33, 93.5, 105.42, 90.75, 104.23, 
    108.86, 102.67, 97, NA, 91.9, 91.38, 93.5, NaN, 98, 94.78, 
    95.1, 93.4), ARG_G1_150_AAC = c(96.38, 90.9, 100, 96.08, 
    NaN, 99.5, 95.82, 106.33, 106.6, 106.5, 92, 95.83, 104, 89, 
    103.75, 109, 96.92, NA, 93, 93.17, 95.12, 102.75, NaN, 93.5, 
    89.38, 102.09, 104.12, 85.44, 103.38, 96.75, 99.2, 98.5, 
    NA, 90.38, 99.18, 105.89, NA, 99.43, 97, 84, NA, NA, 86.75, 
    91.88, NA, 96.86, 98.64, 103.71, 94.22, 95.22, 105.71, NA, 
    NA, NA, 102.33, 94.25, 108.08, 91.75, 107, 112.29, 106.33, 
    98.22, NA, 93.5, 93.25, 94.25, NaN, 100, 96.78, 97.8, 95.5
    ), ARG_G1_150_AC = c(8.75, 10.1, 3.67, 5.23, NaN, 6.5, 6.73, 
    4.78, 2.27, 3.17, 12, 9.83, 3.44, 21.1, 4.25, 2, 11.85, NA, 
    17.5, 6.17, 7.25, 3, NaN, 13.5, 10.62, 5, 5.75, 17.44, 4, 
    10.75, 5, 5.5, NA, 9.5, 9.36, 3.56, NA, 10, 6.86, 9.5, NA, 
    NA, 16.25, 10.25, NA, 10.43, 6, 6.21, 9.22, 9.22, 5.14, NA, 
    NA, NA, 3, 10.75, 6, 12.88, 3.77, 2.57, 4.33, 7.22, NA, 8.6, 
    7.88, 10, NaN, 7, 11.67, 7.8, 7.7), ARG_G1_150_AB = c(10.12, 
    12.6, 5.33, 5.77, NaN, 6.5, 7.91, 5.44, 2.53, 4.33, 12, 9.83, 
    4.78, 21.4, 5.25, 3, 13.77, NA, 17.5, 7.33, 7.25, 6, NaN, 
    16.5, 11.5, 5, 6.25, 18.67, 4.5, 11.38, 5.8, 8.5, NA, 10, 
    9.82, 4.33, NA, 11, 7.71, 9.5, NA, NA, 16.25, 10.25, NA, 
    10.86, 6, 7, 9.22, 10.33, 6.43, NA, NA, NA, 3.33, 11.75, 
    6, 14, 3.77, 2.57, 4.33, 8.22, NA, 8.8, 9, 12, NaN, 8, 12.67, 
    8.2, 8.4), ARG_G1_200_AAA = c(121.5, 110.6, NaN, 120.57, 
    NaN, NaN, 115.67, 132.4, 131.11, 128.5, NaN, 114.5, 126.25, 
    107.4, 124.67, NaN, 120.5, NA, 108, 110.5, 114.33, 125, NaN, 
    114.67, 108, 123.5, 126.67, 105.5, 129.67, 117.75, 121, 120, 
    NA, 108.5, 122.83, 130.8, NA, 123.67, 119, NaN, NA, NA, NaN, 
    109.75, NA, 119, 114.75, 128.88, 115.25, 117, 134, NA, NA, 
    NA, NaN, 113, 131.86, 110.67, 133.57, 138.33, 127.5, 118.25, 
    NA, 112.8, 111.5, 113, NaN, NaN, 114.25, 118, 112.8), ARG_G1_200_AAC = c(123.25, 
    111.6, NaN, 121.29, NaN, NaN, 116.33, 133.4, 132.89, 130.5, 
    NaN, 115.5, 129.5, 108.2, 128.33, NaN, 123, NA, 108, 111.5, 
    115.67, 125, NaN, 118, 112, 125.17, 129, 105.75, 130.33, 
    119.5, 121.4, 121, NA, 109.75, 124.33, 133.4, NA, 125, 120.33, 
    NaN, NA, NA, NaN, 110.75, NA, 123, 124, 129.75, 117.5, 117.2, 
    134, NA, NA, NA, NaN, 116, 134.43, 111.33, 135, 141.33, 129.5, 
    119.5, NA, 114, 113.5, 113, NaN, NaN, 115.5, 120.6, 114), 
    ARG_G1_200_AC = c(12, 15.6, NaN, 8, NaN, NaN, 10.83, 7.8, 
    5.33, 6, NaN, 16.5, 6.75, 31.2, 9.33, NaN, 18, NA, 30, 14.5, 
    13, 11, NaN, 19.67, 17, 9, 9.33, 25.5, 8, 16.25, 9.6, 9, 
    NA, 16, 12.67, 6.2, NA, 13.67, 11.67, NaN, NA, NA, NaN, 17.5, 
    NA, 17, 9, 9.5, 14.75, 15.8, 8, NA, NA, NA, NaN, 23, 10.43, 
    21.33, 5.71, 4.67, 10.25, 13.25, NA, 14.6, 13.25, 19, NaN, 
    NaN, 21.5, 13.2, 14.6), ARG_G1_200_AB = c(14, 19.4, NaN, 
    8.71, NaN, NaN, 12.5, 9, 6, 8, NaN, 16.5, 8.5, 31.8, 11, 
    NaN, 21, NA, 30, 15.5, 13, 15, NaN, 24, 18, 9, 10, 27, 9, 
    17.25, 10.8, 12, NA, 17, 13.5, 7.2, NA, 14.67, 14, NaN, NA, 
    NA, NaN, 17.5, NA, 17.67, 9, 10.88, 14.75, 17, 9.67, NA, 
    NA, NA, NaN, 24, 10.43, 23.33, 5.71, 4.67, 10.5, 15, NA, 
    14.8, 14.75, 21, NaN, NaN, 23.25, 13.8, 15.8), ARG_G1_50_AAA = c(36.35, 
    35.88, 36.22, 35.72, 36.12, 36.96, 35.24, 37.62, 36.05, 34.63, 
    34.19, 33.71, 36.22, 34.43, 34.95, 34.59, 36.03, NA, 32.61, 
    35.29, 37.17, 37.13, 35.62, 34.64, 34.4, 35.69, 37.36, 36.4, 
    36.69, 35.8, 36.57, 35.97, NA, 36.44, 34.94, 35.26, NA, 34.44, 
    37.85, 33.15, NA, NA, 36.13, 34.91, NA, 35.54, 29.02, 35.55, 
    35.64, 35.79, 35.93, NA, NA, NA, 37, 32.58, 35.71, 34.98, 
    36.64, 33.29, 35.29, 37.2, NA, 36.29, 36.91, 31.26, 34, 37.48, 
    33.89, 36.34, 35.88), ARG_G1_50_AAC = c(41.19, 38.7, 41.22, 
    40.53, 44.12, 41.04, 40.18, 42.38, 42.17, 41.87, 38, 41.21, 
    42.24, 38.69, 42.64, 42.14, 41.53, NA, 39.65, 40.76, 41.88, 
    42.23, 39.62, 41.55, 38.19, 42.53, 42.24, 39.49, 42.07, 43.3, 
    40.92, 39.92, NA, 40.35, 40.49, 44.11, NA, 41.72, 40.64, 
    36.15, NA, NA, 39.03, 40.86, NA, 40.93, 37.95, 42.27, 39.47, 
    39.72, 42.12, NA, NA, NA, 42.11, 39.81, 42.82, 39.12, 42.67, 
    43.02, 43.58, 42.61, NA, 40.04, 41.42, 40.9, 41.5, 41.62, 
    40.02, 41.08, 40.18), ARG_G1_50_AC = c(0.98, 1.5, 0.37, 0.6, 
    0.88, 0.73, 1.51, 0.23, 0.25, 0.42, 1.67, 1.58, 0.31, 3.27, 
    0.62, 0.05, 0.83, NA, 3.71, 1.47, 1.07, 0.1, 1.81, 1.19, 
    1.62, 0.61, 0.76, 1.73, 0.24, 0.64, 0.33, 0.97, NA, 0.6, 
    1.98, 0.34, NA, 1.69, 0.26, 2.12, NA, NA, 1.5, 1.14, NA, 
    1, 0.65, 0.88, 1.62, 1.3, 0.39, NA, NA, NA, 0.57, 1.48, 0.58, 
    2.21, 0.43, 0.24, 0.16, 0.65, NA, 0.96, 0.4, 1.13, 1.5, 1.05, 
    1.91, 0.7, 0.94), ARG_G1_50_AB = c(1.09, 2.24, 0.74, 0.68, 
    0.88, 0.73, 1.82, 0.38, 0.36, 0.89, 1.67, 1.58, 0.76, 3.27, 
    0.83, 0.45, 1.15, NA, 3.71, 1.82, 1.07, 1.16, 2.25, 1.93, 
    1.86, 0.61, 1, 2.09, 0.31, 0.86, 0.61, 1.73, NA, 0.77, 2.18, 
    0.34, NA, 1.92, 0.49, 2.12, NA, NA, 1.5, 1.14, NA, 1.2, 0.65, 
    0.88, 1.62, 1.49, 0.63, NA, NA, NA, 0.57, 1.77, 0.58, 2.6, 
    0.43, 0.24, 0.16, 0.85, NA, 0.96, 0.4, 1.84, 1.5, 1.05, 2.4, 
    0.76, 1.14), ARG_G2_100_AAA = c(64.9, 63.8, 71.73, 67.67, 
    NA, NA, 52.5, 72.35, 65.28, 57.22, NA, NaN, 69, 66.67, NaN, 
    66.58, 69, 60.55, 56.29, 67.45, 68.4, 64.25, NaN, 50.86, 
    67.83, 65.96, 57, 53.07, 66.89, NaN, NA, 59, 61.5, NA, 65.9, 
    64.07, NA, NA, 57.91, 67.89, 68.75, 68.5, NaN, 63.24, 66.19, 
    60.59, 59.24, 54.33, 64.39, 65.83, 65.71, 63, 63.78, 63.62, 
    64, 65.08, NA, 67.61, 67.57, 72.71, 65.46, 61.71, NA, 57.62, 
    NA, NA, NA, 64, 61.33, 62.64, NA), ARG_G2_100_AAC = c(65.7, 
    65.8, 74.45, 68, NA, NA, 53.75, 73.94, 67.24, 58.22, NA, 
    NaN, 71.07, 68.07, NaN, 69.88, 71.32, 62.18, 58.65, 76.45, 
    71.13, 67.25, NaN, 51.76, 69.33, 68.17, 58, 54.27, 68.05, 
    NaN, NA, 61, 61.67, NA, 67.79, 65.93, NA, NA, 59.27, 69.67, 
    71.38, 70, NaN, 64.88, 68.19, 62.06, 61, 55.48, 65.67, 67.72, 
    68.47, 64, 65.11, 66, 67.5, 66.33, NA, 69.61, 69.33, 75.67, 
    68.17, 63, NA, 58.81, NA, NA, NA, 66.5, 62.33, 65, NA), ARG_G2_100_AC = c(7.1, 
    6.4, 0.18, 3.67, NA, NA, 12.75, 1.24, 2.96, 9.78, NA, NaN, 
    1.43, 1.33, NaN, 5.21, 2.76, 7.91, 8.06, 2.36, 2.87, 4, NaN, 
    15.52, 2.67, 4.17, 13, 10.07, 5.05, NaN, NA, 9.5, 8.17, NA, 
    5.86, 3.87, NA, NA, 7, 3.33, 1.75, 3, NaN, 7.94, 3.11, 5.29, 
    5.29, 13.1, 3.78, 3.33, 3.06, 5.18, 2.56, 5.04, 5.5, 5.75, 
    NA, 2.22, 2.48, 1, 3.83, 4.82, NA, 8.19, NA, NA, NA, 5, 6.44, 
    5.29, NA), ARG_G2_100_AB = c(7.1, 7.4, 1.09, 3.67, NA, NA, 
    12.75, 1.24, 3.28, 9.78, NA, NaN, 1.71, 1.93, NaN, 6.21, 
    2.76, 7.91, 8.65, 3.55, 3.4, 5, NaN, 16.05, 3.39, 4.52, 13, 
    11.6, 5.05, NaN, NA, 9.5, 9.67, NA, 7.03, 3.87, NA, NA, 8, 
    3.33, 2.19, 3, NaN, 8.53, 3.37, 5.47, 7.35, 13.48, 5.33, 
    3.83, 3.65, 5.82, 4, 6.17, 6, 6.42, NA, 3.83, 2.71, 2.19, 
    4.58, 5.18, NA, 9.75, NA, NA, NA, 5, 6.44, 5.36, NA), ARG_G2_150_AAA = c(85.25, 
    NaN, 99, NaN, NA, NA, 66.86, 101, 89.31, 71.33, NA, NaN, 
    94.5, 88.57, NaN, 95, 95.5, 81.5, 78.5, 107.75, 93.43, NaN, 
    NaN, 66.18, 92.33, 92.25, NaN, 67.43, 87.44, NaN, NA, NaN, 
    78, NA, 89.81, 86.43, NA, NA, 75.75, 91.67, 95, NaN, NaN, 
    85.12, 91.47, 81.88, 79.38, 72.45, 87.67, 91.22, 90.88, 83, 
    85, 89.23, NaN, 86.2, NA, 92, 93.09, 100.27, 88.62, 83.88, 
    NA, 75, NA, NA, NA, NaN, 80, 83.5, NA), ARG_G2_150_AAC = c(86.75, 
    NaN, 101, NaN, NA, NA, 67.29, 103.75, 91.15, 71.67, NA, NaN, 
    96.33, 88.86, NaN, 96.23, 97.5, 83.5, 79.12, 109.5, 95, NaN, 
    NaN, 66.45, 93.56, 93.42, NaN, 68, 88.33, NaN, NA, NaN, 78, 
    NA, 91.69, 87, NA, NA, 76.75, 93, 96.88, NaN, NaN, 85.5, 
    92.67, 83.38, 80.25, 73.09, 88.33, 92.44, 92.38, 84.25, 85.33, 
    91.23, NaN, 87.8, NA, 92.67, 94.09, 102.09, 90.15, 84.75, 
    NA, 76.14, NA, NA, NA, NaN, 81, 85.67, NA), ARG_G2_150_AC = c(15.75, 
    NaN, 1, NaN, NA, NA, 25.71, 2.62, 6.85, 19.33, NA, NaN, 3.83, 
    4.57, NaN, 9.85, 6.5, 15.5, 13.88, 3.75, 6.29, NaN, NaN, 
    27.36, 5.67, 8.42, NaN, 18.86, 11.33, NaN, NA, NaN, 19, NA, 
    11.25, 9.57, NA, NA, 12.75, 6, 4.5, NaN, NaN, 15.75, 5.67, 
    10.75, 9.75, 24.82, 8.67, 6.67, 5.88, 13.25, 7, 10, NaN, 
    10.6, NA, 6.56, 4.18, 2.55, 8.54, 9.75, NA, 17.86, NA, NA, 
    NA, NaN, 15.67, 13.17, NA), ARG_G2_150_AB = c(15.75, NaN, 
    2, NaN, NA, NA, 25.71, 2.62, 8.69, 19.33, NA, NaN, 4.33, 
    5.43, NaN, 11.31, 6.5, 15.5, 14.75, 6, 7.14, NaN, NaN, 28.27, 
    7.22, 9, NaN, 21.29, 11.33, NaN, NA, NaN, 22, NA, 13.44, 
    9.71, NA, NA, 14.75, 6, 5.12, NaN, NaN, 16.75, 6, 11.25, 
    12.75, 25.36, 11.11, 7.33, 6.62, 14.25, 9.33, 11.62, NaN, 
    11.8, NA, 9.22, 4.91, 4.64, 10, 10.38, NA, 19.86, NA, NA, 
    NA, NaN, 15.67, 13.33, NA), ARG_G2_200_AAA = c(NaN, NaN, 
    125, NaN, NA, NA, 81.33, 129.5, 112.25, NaN, NA, NaN, 117.5, 
    108.33, NaN, 120, 119.25, 99, 94, 134, 113.67, NaN, NaN, 
    77.67, 112.25, 112.86, NaN, 78.33, 106.6, NaN, NA, NaN, NaN, 
    NA, 112.4, 106.67, NA, NA, 93, NaN, 122, NaN, NaN, 104.25, 
    114.89, 101.25, 96.75, 87, 107, 112.25, 112.25, 100, NaN, 
    111.86, NaN, 101, NA, 114, 114.5, 124.17, 108.86, 103.25, 
    NA, 90.67, NA, NA, NA, NaN, NaN, 99, NA), ARG_G2_200_AAC = c(NaN, 
    NaN, 126, NaN, NA, NA, 82.33, 129.75, 113.5, NaN, NA, NaN, 
    118, 109.33, NaN, 120.71, 120.25, 101, 94.25, 136, 114, NaN, 
    NaN, 78, 114, 114, NaN, 78.67, 106.8, NaN, NA, NaN, NaN, 
    NA, 114, 108.33, NA, NA, 93, NaN, 123, NaN, NaN, 104.25, 
    116.67, 102.75, 97.25, 87.67, 107.75, 113.25, 113.25, 101, 
    NaN, 113.14, NaN, 101, NA, 114.5, 115, 126.17, 111.29, 104.25, 
    NA, 92, NA, NA, NA, NaN, NaN, 99, NA), ARG_G2_200_AC = c(NaN, 
    NaN, 1, NaN, NA, NA, 36, 5.25, 12.25, NaN, NA, NaN, 8.5, 
    8.33, NaN, 14.29, 11.38, 24, 22.25, 6, 11.67, NaN, NaN, 42.5, 
    9.25, 13.14, NaN, 32, 19.4, NaN, NA, NaN, NaN, NA, 15.6, 
    17, NA, NA, 24, NaN, 6.67, NaN, NaN, 21.5, 8.89, 17.5, 16, 
    37.83, 15.75, 12.25, 11.75, 20, NaN, 15.43, NaN, 26, NA, 
    12.25, 7.5, 5.67, 12.86, 14.75, NA, 27, NA, NA, NA, NaN, 
    NaN, 28.5, NA), ARG_G2_200_AB = c(NaN, NaN, 2, NaN, NA, NA, 
    36, 5.25, 16, NaN, NA, NaN, 10, 9.33, NaN, 16.57, 11.38, 
    24, 23.25, 9, 13, NaN, NaN, 44.33, 11.5, 14.29, NaN, 35, 
    19.4, NaN, NA, NaN, NaN, NA, 18.8, 17.33, NA, NA, 26, NaN, 
    7.67, NaN, NaN, 22.5, 9.33, 18.25, 20.25, 38.67, 19, 13.25, 
    13.25, 22, NaN, 18, NaN, 28, NA, 15.75, 8.83, 8.17, 15.14, 
    16, NA, 29.33, NA, NA, NA, NaN, NaN, 29, NA), ARG_G2_50_AAA = c(36.97, 
    35.4, 34.72, 33.81, NA, NA, 32.98, 35.7, 35.59, 35.36, NA, 
    36, 37.66, 36.35, 33.44, 34.72, 36.9, 34.32, 32.28, 33.74, 
    36.38, 35.06, 34.5, 31.47, 36.59, 36.18, 34.75, 31.9, 36.53, 
    32.62, NA, 33.85, 34.86, NA, 35.36, 34.52, NA, NA, 33.68, 
    35.89, 36.24, 37.21, 28, 34.05, 36.3, 34.16, 32.86, 32.06, 
    34.65, 35.57, 35.95, 33.19, 34.61, 34.6, 34.92, 34.24, NA, 
    34.33, 35.65, 36.16, 33.91, 34.37, NA, 33.44, NA, NA, NA, 
    33.93, 33.71, 35.42, NA), ARG_G2_50_AAC = c(40.2, 38.6, 42.09, 
    39.25, NA, NA, 35.68, 41.41, 39.12, 37.68, NA, 39, 41.16, 
    40.67, 36.11, 39.25, 40.65, 37.52, 35.14, 41.26, 41.13, 40.71, 
    36.25, 33.33, 40.59, 39.67, 36.83, 34.44, 40.57, 34, NA, 
    37, 36.45, NA, 39.52, 38.17, NA, NA, 36.52, 40.39, 40.69, 
    41.21, 29, 39.63, 40.23, 37.27, 36.58, 34.45, 38.87, 38.98, 
    39.51, 38.13, 37.68, 37.88, 38.85, 38.48, NA, 40, 40.43, 
    42.73, 39.93, 38.19, NA, 36.41, NA, NA, NA, 39.71, 36.43, 
    38.03, NA), ARG_G2_50_AC = c(0.8, 1.9, 0, 0.5, NA, NA, 2.93, 
    0.52, 0.58, 2.75, NA, 1.25, 0.21, 0.25, 2.11, 2, 0.85, 2.03, 
    2.67, 0.71, 0.82, 0.29, 0.75, 4.27, 0.63, 0.78, 2.92, 2.77, 
    1.17, 4.88, NA, 3, 2.64, NA, 1.78, 0.98, NA, NA, 2.29, 0.82, 
    0.45, 0.93, 6, 1.67, 0.86, 1.27, 1.79, 3.37, 1.11, 0.74, 
    0.79, 1.1, 0.71, 1.11, 1.08, 2.48, NA, 0.17, 0.75, 0.22, 
    0.91, 1.19, NA, 1.66, NA, NA, NA, 1.07, 1.75, 1.42, NA), 
    ARG_G2_50_AB = c(0.8, 2, 0.31, 0.5, NA, NA, 2.93, 0.52, 0.58, 
    2.75, NA, 1.25, 0.34, 0.5, 3.33, 2.44, 0.85, 2.03, 2.91, 
    1.42, 1, 0.94, 0.75, 4.63, 0.85, 0.96, 2.92, 3.49, 1.17, 
    4.88, NA, 3, 3.36, NA, 2.3, 0.98, NA, NA, 2.61, 0.82, 0.52, 
    0.93, 6, 1.91, 1.02, 1.34, 2.58, 3.67, 1.59, 0.96, 1.09, 
    1.39, 1.5, 1.65, 1.15, 2.76, NA, 0.93, 0.8, 0.82, 1.25, 1.44, 
    NA, 2.49, NA, NA, NA, 1.07, 1.75, 1.47, NA), NARR_G1_100_AAA = c(71.32, 
    NA, NA, 67.83, NaN, 71.6, 64.2, 71.68, 73.29, 70.53, 73.35, 
    59.31, 71.08, 74.06, 68.7, 74, 69.08, NA, 68.52, 63.47, 68.33, 
    NA, 65.64, 62.11, 63.9, 70.41, 60.36, 65.88, 68.81, 69.62, 
    70.68, 67.5, NA, 68.45, 67.16, 74.39, 60.6, 65.89, 71.94, 
    68.75, NA, NA, 67, 66.85, NA, NA, 62.56, 73.33, 69.81, 67.68, 
    73.06, 65.8, 63.85, NA, 67.64, 71.6, 68.47, 69.39, 71.16, 
    72.33, NA, 66.68, NA, 66.22, 67, 61.27, NaN, 72.33, 68.29, 
    71.33, 65.57), NARR_G1_100_AAC = c(74.26, NA, NA, 70.94, 
    NaN, 75, 66.14, 74.48, 77.07, 73.47, 76, 60.44, 73.92, 77.19, 
    71.4, 77.59, 72, NA, 70.38, 65.47, 70.54, NA, 68.09, 64.61, 
    66.5, 72.52, 62.59, 69.25, 71.48, 71.88, 74.4, 70.1, NA, 
    70, 69.6, 78.04, 62.3, 68.79, 73.44, 72.25, NA, NA, 67, 68.25, 
    NA, NA, 65.94, 75.71, 72.43, 69.68, 76, 68.6, 65.65, NA, 
    70.43, 74, 71.76, 71.17, 74.63, 74.22, NA, 69.47, NA, 68.72, 
    67, 62.82, NaN, 77.33, 69.76, 75.42, 67.62), NARR_G1_100_AC = c(3.05, 
    NA, NA, 2.33, NaN, 2.4, 1.89, 0.84, 0.07, 5.47, 1.12, 8.81, 
    2.39, 1.38, 3.6, 0.88, 2.65, NA, 2.05, 5.18, 2.38, NA, 5, 
    4.78, 6.4, 1.85, 7.41, 3.69, 1.85, 2.62, 1.28, 3.9, NA, 2.35, 
    3.8, 1.87, 5.1, 6.95, 1.67, 4.5, NA, NA, 4, 4.25, NA, NA, 
    7.17, 1.29, 2.62, 1.37, 1.47, 3.3, 7.27, NA, 3.64, 3.6, 2.59, 
    4.83, 0.63, 2.28, NA, 6.58, NA, 4.56, 6, 4.82, NaN, 0.67, 
    3.95, 1.75, 4.38), NARR_G1_100_AB = c(3.42, NA, NA, 3.17, 
    NaN, 2.5, 3.29, 1.64, 1.07, 6, 1.41, 9.25, 3.25, 2.69, 3.8, 
    1.32, 3.04, NA, 2.38, 5.18, 2.38, NA, 6.18, 6.11, 6.4, 1.85, 
    7.45, 3.69, 1.89, 3.25, 1.6, 4.8, NA, 2.8, 4.32, 2.3, 6.6, 
    7.42, 2.83, 4.75, NA, NA, 5, 4.75, NA, NA, 8, 1.71, 2.67, 
    2.05, 1.47, 4.8, 7.96, NA, 4.43, 3.8, 4.47, 4.91, 1.68, 2.78, 
    NA, 6.58, NA, 6.67, 6, 5.18, NaN, 1.67, 4.86, 2.08, 4.38), 
    NARR_G1_150_AAA = c(102, NA, NA, 96.22, NaN, 105.33, 87.1, 
    100.14, 106.17, 97.67, 99.88, 75.43, 99.62, 106.86, 95.3, 
    105.68, 97.14, NA, 92.82, 87.25, 96.23, NA, 88.5, 83.56, 
    89.75, 98.47, 80.64, 92.14, 96.07, 94.62, 99.46, 100, NA, 
    92.6, 94.54, 106.25, 82.5, 93.6, 100.33, 95, NA, NA, NaN, 
    90.9, NA, NA, 87.89, 101.08, 96.18, 95, 103.12, 92.75, 85.71, 
    NA, 94.17, NaN, 95.25, 97.5, 100.67, 100.44, NA, 90.9, NA, 
    90.11, NaN, 81.5, NaN, NaN, 94.45, 100.4, 91.64), NARR_G1_150_AAC = c(103.2, 
    NA, NA, 97.67, NaN, 106.67, 88.55, 102.43, 109.17, 98.78, 
    103.25, 76.57, 102.05, 109.43, 97.4, 108.42, 99.29, NA, 94.73, 
    89, 98, NA, 89.75, 85, 91.75, 100.47, 81.64, 93.14, 97.73, 
    96, 101.08, 101.33, NA, 94.1, 95.92, 110.33, 83.25, 95.5, 
    101.67, 98, NA, NA, NaN, 93, NA, NA, 90.56, 102.38, 99, 96.78, 
    106.5, 94.25, 87.43, NA, 98.33, NaN, 99, 98.92, 103.44, 103, 
    NA, 93.8, NA, 92, NaN, 82.25, NaN, NaN, 95.45, 102.8, 93.82
    ), NARR_G1_150_AC = c(6.4, NA, NA, 5.78, NaN, 5, 4.85, 2.29, 
    0.5, 12.44, 2.5, 19, 4.71, 3, 8, 1.63, 5.86, NA, 4.82, 9.25, 
    4.08, NA, 10.75, 9.44, 12.25, 3.6, 15.73, 7.14, 3.73, 7.12, 
    4.08, 6.33, NA, 5.1, 6.62, 3.08, 10.25, 12.5, 4.56, 7.5, 
    NA, NA, NaN, 8.6, NA, NA, 13.67, 3.15, 6, 2.22, 2.5, 8, 15, 
    NA, 6, NaN, 5.5, 8.75, 2.44, 4.33, NA, 13.9, NA, 8.78, NaN, 
    13.75, NaN, NaN, 7.73, 4.4, 9.36), NARR_G1_150_AB = c(7, 
    NA, NA, 7.33, NaN, 5.33, 7.4, 3.71, 2.17, 13.33, 2.88, 20.14, 
    6, 5.14, 8.5, 2.42, 6.43, NA, 5.18, 9.25, 4.08, NA, 12.5, 
    11.56, 12.25, 3.6, 15.73, 7.14, 4, 8.12, 4.46, 7.33, NA, 
    5.9, 7.54, 3.67, 13, 13.3, 6.78, 8, NA, NA, NaN, 9.1, NA, 
    NA, 15.11, 4.15, 6.09, 3.22, 2.5, 10.5, 16.29, NA, 7.33, 
    NaN, 8.38, 8.83, 4, 5.22, NA, 13.9, NA, 12.11, NaN, 15.25, 
    NaN, NaN, 9.27, 5, 9.36), NARR_G1_200_AAA = c(127.8, NA, 
    NA, 120.25, NaN, NaN, 105.85, 126.62, 134.5, 121.4, 126.25, 
    89.33, 126.23, 136, 120.4, 133.17, 124, NA, 115.5, 106.5, 
    120.86, NA, 115, 104.25, NaN, 123.22, 100, 114, 120.22, 115.67, 
    124.38, NaN, NA, 112.6, 119, 137.29, NaN, 118.4, 127, NaN, 
    NA, NA, NaN, 113.8, NA, NA, 111.5, 123.57, 122.33, 118.8, 
    130, NaN, 106.38, NA, 123.5, NaN, 123.75, 123.29, 127.2, 
    126.5, NA, 113.8, NA, 113.75, NaN, 101, NaN, NaN, 117.83, 
    125, 114.5), NARR_G1_200_AAC = c(130, NA, NA, 123, NaN, NaN, 
    107.54, 128.75, 136.5, 123, 128.5, 90, 128, 137.33, 121.6, 
    136.92, 125.5, NA, 117, 108.25, 122.29, NA, 115, 105, NaN, 
    125.11, 102, 116, 122.33, 117.33, 126.25, NaN, NA, 114.6, 
    121.12, 138.86, NaN, 119.2, 127.75, NaN, NA, NA, NaN, 114.4, 
    NA, NA, 113, 124.43, 124, 120.6, 133, NaN, 107, NA, 124.5, 
    NaN, 127.75, 123.57, 129, 127.5, NA, 115.6, NA, 117, NaN, 
    101, NaN, NaN, 118.5, 129, 115.5), NARR_G1_200_AC = c(11.2, 
    NA, NA, 12.5, NaN, NaN, 9.31, 4.25, 2, 17.8, 4.5, 32.33, 
    7.77, 5.67, 13.4, 2.67, 9.62, NA, 7.67, 15, 6.14, NA, 16, 
    14.75, NaN, 6.22, 24.33, 11, 6.67, 14.33, 7.62, NaN, NA, 
    9.4, 9.75, 4.86, NaN, 18.6, 8.25, NaN, NA, NA, NaN, 13.8, 
    NA, NA, 21.75, 6.14, 9.33, 6, 4.5, NaN, 23.75, NA, 8.5, NaN, 
    6.75, 13.86, 3.8, 6.75, NA, 21.4, NA, 12.75, NaN, 20, NaN, 
    NaN, 12.83, 7, 15.83), NARR_G1_200_AB = c(12, NA, NA, 14.5, 
    NaN, NaN, 12.85, 6.38, 4.5, 18.8, 5.25, 34.67, 9.54, 8.67, 
    14.4, 4, 10.62, NA, 8.33, 15, 6.29, NA, 18, 17.5, NaN, 6.22, 
    24.33, 11.33, 7, 15.33, 8.12, NaN, NA, 10.8, 11, 5.71, NaN, 
    19.6, 10.75, NaN, NA, NA, NaN, 14.6, NA, NA, 24, 7.57, 9.5, 
    8, 5, NaN, 25.75, NA, 10.5, NaN, 10.5, 14, 6, 8.75, NA, 21.4, 
    NA, 17.75, NaN, 22, NaN, NaN, 15.5, 8, 15.83), NARR_G1_50_AAA = c(37.69, 
    NA, NA, 37.02, 35.38, 34.34, 36.19, 37.25, 36.78, 36.83, 
    36.61, 34.2, 34.24, 37.51, 35.74, 34, 35.02, NA, 37.4, 36.18, 
    36.63, NA, 34.42, 34.38, 35.43, 37.2, 34.49, 34.2, 36.41, 
    37.07, 36.56, 34.93, NA, 36.06, 36.49, 35.31, 33.33, 34.27, 
    36.5, 36.5, NA, NA, 34.21, 36.02, NA, NA, 34.02, 35.59, 37.16, 
    36.02, 37.58, 36.53, 35.46, NA, 36.46, 38.42, 36.05, 37.39, 
    37.3, 36.22, NA, 35.31, NA, 33.96, 35.55, 35.03, 35, 35.31, 
    36.54, 36.06, 34.98), NARR_G1_50_AAC = c(41.85, NA, NA, 40.71, 
    37.5, 42.38, 39.05, 41.98, 42.51, 42.47, 43.43, 36.41, 42.17, 
    43.27, 40.42, 43.1, 40.52, NA, 41.65, 38.82, 40.63, NA, 40.35, 
    39.18, 38.93, 41.44, 38.3, 39.54, 40.73, 41.83, 42.54, 40.34, 
    NA, 40.69, 40.31, 43.51, 36.13, 39.1, 41.65, 41.62, NA, NA, 
    38.57, 40.02, NA, NA, 38.26, 42.66, 41.55, 39.7, 42.91, 40.43, 
    38.87, NA, 40.86, 43.26, 40.55, 40.84, 42.13, 42.09, NA, 
    40.31, NA, 39.69, 39.73, 36.97, 37.71, 43.44, 40.44, 42.33, 
    39.65), NARR_G1_50_AC = c(0.77, NA, NA, 0.69, 2.25, 0.45, 
    0.59, 0.12, 0, 1.15, 0.34, 2.61, 0.61, 0.24, 0.64, 0.26, 
    0.79, NA, 0.19, 1.43, 0.65, NA, 1.39, 1.11, 1.87, 0.31, 1.98, 
    1.07, 0.54, 0.29, 0.24, 0.76, NA, 0.59, 1.05, 0.62, 2.17, 
    2.25, 0.33, 1.62, NA, NA, 1.36, 1.53, NA, NA, 2.22, 0.22, 
    0.65, 0.45, 0.42, 0.9, 2.18, NA, 0.97, 0.05, 0.84, 0.98, 
    0, 0.44, NA, 1.83, NA, 1.71, 0.91, 1.16, 1.86, 0.12, 0.69, 
    0.45, 1.24), NARR_G1_50_AB = c(0.88, NA, NA, 0.82, 2.25, 
    0.45, 1.03, 0.45, 0.54, 1.36, 0.55, 2.71, 0.96, 0.73, 0.64, 
    0.47, 0.97, NA, 0.29, 1.43, 0.65, NA, 1.81, 1.69, 1.87, 0.31, 
    2.02, 1.07, 0.54, 0.52, 0.39, 1.1, NA, 0.8, 1.31, 0.82, 2.9, 
    2.44, 0.74, 1.62, NA, NA, 1.86, 1.76, NA, NA, 2.48, 0.38, 
    0.67, 0.66, 0.42, 1.67, 2.38, NA, 1.43, 0.16, 1.64, 1.04, 
    0.57, 0.69, NA, 1.83, NA, 2.6, 0.91, 1.16, 2.71, 0.75, 0.98, 
    0.58, 1.24), NARR_G2_100_AAA = c(64.25, 59, NA, 67.88, 67.08, 
    NA, 60.75, 64.42, 71.17, 58.42, NA, 49.8, 63.36, 65.2, NaN, 
    70.2, 62.85, NaN, 61.6, 53.92, 62.63, NA, NaN, 50.46, 65.14, 
    60.58, 63.29, NA, 64.33, NaN, NA, 68.57, NA, NA, 66.3, NA, 
    57.29, NA, 53.5, 63.48, NA, 57.07, NaN, 61.82, NA, 68.61, 
    57.1, 62.84, 63, 61.91, 58.38, NaN, 61.56, NA, NaN, 65.55, 
    63.8, 65, 63.14, 67.31, 67.75, 57.62, 63.31, 54.83, 66.43, 
    NA, NA, 64.67, 57.92, 59, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -71L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I think `dput(head(dfPaired, n=some_sufficient_#_of_cases_that_pair_on_final_alphas))` as data might come in handy here.

Comment: @Chris all right, here it goes! I've just edited the post with the ```dput``` output. There's also some more details in the original post, if it helps. :) PS: I've put 1:50 because the post would be too long according to the limits, but I have 65 collumns (including ID)

Comment: I actually did just mean `dfPaired` the strings, rather than all the data.

Comment: oh, my bad! Then that's already in the other post :)

Comment: Could you please state the problem in this post so we don't have to go to another question to link it? Are you trying to select columns discarding others? Or only reorder columns? When you say you want `ARG_G1_50_AAA, ARG_G2_50_AAA, ARG_G1_50_AAC, ARG_G2_50_AAC, ARG_G1_50_AC, ARG_G2_50_AC,...` could you spend a sentence or two explaining the logic, just to make sure we're not making bad assumptions about what you want?

Comment: @GregorThomas , Ok, I'll add more details here in a moment! (I was afraid of the post becoming too long)

Comment: For example, it seems like all your columns have a naming pattern `ARG_{Gnumber}_{number2}_{Astring}`, and it looks like you want to sort the columns first by `{number2}` then by `{Astring}` then by `{Gnumber}`. Is that accurate?

Comment: I've just edit the post, is it clear now? Please let me know.  Thank you, so yes, it's always: ```ARG_{Gnumber}_{number2}_{Astring}``` or ```NARR_{Gnumber}_{number2}_{Astring}```. For **Set1** I need ```SAME_{G1}_{50}_{AAA}``` followed by  ```SAME_{G2}_{50}_{AAA}```, for. Ex. and, yes, the order should be G1 followed by G2  in ascending order {number2} (50, 100, 150, 200) and in the {Astring} order (AAA, AAC, AC, AB)

Comment: We can think of it as "blocks" in relation to {number2}. I have a block of 50, then 100, then 150 and finally 200. What is inside each "block" should be in the same order

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest pulling your column names into a data frame, separating them into their components, and ordering them as desired:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
col_df = data.frame(names = names(merged_DF)[-1]) ## -1 to skip the ID col
col_df = col_df %>%
  separate(
    col = names, sep = "_",
    into = c("s1", "gnum", "num2", "astring"),
    remove = FALSE, convert = TRUE
  ) %>%
  arrange(s1, num2, astring, gnum) 

## now we have the names in order:
col_df
#              names   s1 gnum num2 astring
# 1    ARG_G1_50_AAA  ARG   G1   50     AAA
# 2    ARG_G2_50_AAA  ARG   G2   50     AAA
# 3    ARG_G1_50_AAC  ARG   G1   50     AAC
# 4    ARG_G2_50_AAC  ARG   G2   50     AAC
# 5     ARG_G1_50_AB  ARG   G1   50      AB
# 6     ARG_G2_50_AB  ARG   G2   50      AB
# 7     ARG_G1_50_AC  ARG   G1   50      AC
# 8     ARG_G2_50_AC  ARG   G2   50      AC
# 9   ARG_G1_100_AAA  ARG   G1  100     AAA
# 10  ARG_G2_100_AAA  ARG   G2  100     AAA
# ...

## we can use this order to rearrange the columns
merged_DF = select(merged_DF, c(ID, col_df$names))
names(merged_DF)
# [1] "ID"              "ARG_G1_50_AAA"   "ARG_G2_50_AAA"   "ARG_G1_50_AAC"   "ARG_G2_50_AAC"  
#  [6] "ARG_G1_50_AB"    "ARG_G2_50_AB"    "ARG_G1_50_AC"    "ARG_G2_50_AC"    "ARG_G1_100_AAA" 
# [11] "ARG_G2_100_AAA"  "ARG_G1_100_AAC"  "ARG_G2_100_AAC"  "ARG_G1_100_AB"   "ARG_G2_100_AB"  
# [16] "ARG_G1_100_AC"   "ARG_G2_100_AC"   "ARG_G1_150_AAA"  "ARG_G2_150_AAA"  "ARG_G1_150_AAC" 
# [21] "ARG_G2_150_AAC"  "ARG_G1_150_AB"   "ARG_G2_150_AB"   "ARG_G1_150_AC"   "ARG_G2_150_AC"  
# [26] "ARG_G1_200_AAA"  "ARG_G2_200_AAA"  "ARG_G1_200_AAC"  "ARG_G2_200_AAC"  "ARG_G1_200_AB"  
# [31] "ARG_G2_200_AB"   "ARG_G1_200_AC"   "ARG_G2_200_AC"   "NARR_G1_50_AAA"  "NARR_G1_50_AAC" 
# [36] "NARR_G1_50_AB"   "NARR_G1_50_AC"   "NARR_G1_100_AAA" "NARR_G2_100_AAA" "NARR_G1_100_AAC"
# [41] "NARR_G1_100_AB"  "NARR_G1_100_AC"  "NARR_G1_150_AAA" "NARR_G1_150_AAC" "NARR_G1_150_AB" 
# [46] "NARR_G1_150_AC"  "NARR_G1_200_AAA" "NARR_G1_200_AAC" "NARR_G1_200_AB"  "NARR_G1_200_AC"
```

Comment: Wowww, thank you!! it worked perfectly!! Is there a way to extend this to **set2** too? I mean, since "A" comes before "N", it always rearrages all ARGs and all NARRs, but I also need them intercalated as: Arg_G1_50_AAA then Narr_G1_50_AAA so on... (no need to intercalate G1 and G2 now)

Comment: Sure, I called the `ARG`/`NARR` component "s1", and I put it first in the `arrange`. But you can put it in a different position instead. Change `arrange(s1, num2, astring, gnum)` to `arrange(num2, s1, astring, gnum)`, or whatever order you prefer. See the `?arrange` help page for details.

Comment: Also, I will comment that I've never heard the word "intercalate" before, and looking up definitions I don't think that's at all what I'm doing. I'm just sorting. If you were generating these from raw strings, maybe that would be intercalating? But it mostly confuses me when you say things like *"no need to intercalate G1 and G2 now"*.

Comment: ohhhh, Portuguese is my first language, we have "intercalar". Maybe the best translation would be "interpolate", but since its a statistical method, I've used "intercalate" in order to avoid confusion (I thought that that was an Eng word too, my bad! I'll change the posts' title, thanks for the comment.

Comment: Ps: In *set2*, I need ARG followed by NARR ... what I meant is that now I don't need to interpolate G1 and G2, I only need G1. What needs to be interpoled/alternated is Arg and Narr, but I still didn't get it. I guess that maybe because its following the alphabetic order? desired output: ```Arg_G1_50_AAA``` followed by ```NARR_G1_50_AAA``` followed by ```Arg_G1_50_AAC``` followed by ```NARR_G1_50_AAC```  so on....

Comment: Just think about it as sorting. What changes fastest? Arg/NARR - so `s1` goes last in `arrange`. What changes next fastest? Looks like `astring`, so that is 2nd to last. Next is `gnum`, and then `num2` changes slowest. So `arrange(num2, gnum, astring, s1)`.

Comment: What I don't understand now is your "set1" vs "set2". Are these different data sets? Or are the sets of columns in the same data set? If sets of columns in the same data set, how do you tell them apart? What makes a name part of set 1 vs set 2?

Comment: oh, they're  two subsets of my dataset. I'm gonna use each subset for different tests (that's why I needed two different orders). Thank you VERY much! Now everything is working this fine!

Answer (score 1):

I bet that there are simpler ways of doing this but this one seems to work.

```
intercalate <- function(X, pattern) {
  f <- function(h, n) {
    i <- seq(1, length(h), by = 2)
    j <- seq(2, length(h), by = 2)
    h[order(c(i, j))]
  }
  #
  g <- function(x, y) {
    nx <- length(x)
    ny <- length(y)
    if(nx == ny) {
      h <- c(x, y)
      f(h, nx)
    } else if(nx > ny) {
      h <- c(x[seq_along(y)], y)
      h <- f(h, ny)
      c(h, x[-seq_along(y)])
    } else {
      h <- c(x, y[seq_along(x)])
      h <- f(h, nx)
      c(h, y[-seq_along(x)])
    }
  }
  #
  s <- grepl(pattern = pattern, X)
  s <- abs(c(0, diff(s)))
  sp <- split(X, cumsum(s))
  i_odd <- seq(1, length(sp), by = 2)
  i_even <- seq(2, length(sp), by = 2)
  new_names <- mapply(g, sp[i_odd], sp[i_even])
  unname(unlist(new_names))
}

newnames <- intercalate(names(merged_DF)[-1], pattern = "G2")
newnames <- c(names(merged_DF)[1], newnames)
merged_DF[newnames]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably insufficient to the task:

```
strings <- c('ARG_G1_50_AAA' ,'ARG_G1_50_AAC', 'ARG_G1_50_AC' ,'ARG_G1_50_AB', 
              'ARG_G2_50_AAA' ,'ARG_G2_50_AAC', 'ARG_G2_50_AC')

substring(strings, regexpr('_\\K[[:upper:]]{2,3}', strings, perl = TRUE), nchar(strings))
[1] "AAA" "AAC" "AC"  "AB"  "AAA" "AAC" "AC" 

idx_strings <- order(substring(strings, regexpr('_\\K[[:upper:]]{2,3}', strings, perl = TRUE), nchar(strings)))

idx_strings
[1] 1 5 2 6 4 3 7

> strings[idx_strings]
[1] "ARG_G1_50_AAA" "ARG_G2_50_AAA" "ARG_G1_50_AAC" "ARG_G2_50_AAC"
[5] "ARG_G1_50_AB"  "ARG_G1_50_AC"  "ARG_G2_50_AC"
```

Getting nearly desired 'set1' results for 'NARR_' and 'ARG_' as follows
for 'NARR_', using @akrun data [v1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73941682/how-to-dynamically-intercalate-columns-with-pattern-in-r), though `[7] & [8]` appear reversed

```
idx_v1_N <- which(regexpr('^[N]', v1, perl = TRUE) == 1)

v1[idx_v1_N[order(
substring(v1[idx_v1_N],
regexpr('[^_.G][\\d_]\\d.+[[:upper:]]', v1[idx_v1_N], perl = TRUE), 
nchar(v1[idx_v1_N]))[idx_v1_N])]]
 [1] "NARR_G1_100_AAC" "NARR_G1_100_AB"  "NARR_G2_100_AC"  "NARR_G1_150_AAC"
 [5] "NARR_G1_150_AB"  "NARR_G1_100_AAA" "NARR_G2_150_AAA" "NARR_G2_100_AAA"
 [9] "NARR_G1_100_AC"  "NARR_G1_150_AAA" "NARR_G1_150_AC"  "NARR_G2_100_AAC"
[13] "NARR_G2_50_AB"   "NARR_G1_50_AC"   "NARR_G1_50_AAA"  "NARR_G2_150_AB" 
[17] "NARR_G2_150_AAC" "NARR_G2_50_AC"   "NARR_G1_50_AAC"  "NARR_G2_150_AC" 
[21] "NARR_G1_50_AB"   "NARR_G2_100_AB"  "NARR_G2_50_AAA"  "NARR_G2_50_AAC"
```

the substring and regexpr `'[^_.G][\\d_]\\d.+[[:upper:]]'` return

```
substring(v1[idx_v1_N], regexpr('[^_.G][\\d_]\\d.+[[:upper:]]', v1[idx_v1_N], perl = TRUE), nchar(v1[idx_v1_N]))
 [1] "1_100_AB"  "1_150_AAC" "2_50_AB"   "1_150_AB"  "2_100_AAA" "1_100_AAC"
 [7] "1_150_AAA" "2_100_AC"  "1_100_AAA" "1_150_AC"  "2_100_AAC" "2_150_AAA"
[13] "1_100_AC"  "1_50_AC"   "1_50_AAA"  "2_150_AB"  "2_150_AAC" "2_50_AC"  
[19] "1_50_AAC"  "2_150_AC"  "1_50_AB"   "2_100_AB"  "2_50_AAA"  "2_50_AAC"
```

which is then order([ed] nearly correctly. Results for 'ARG_' just need  an index for starting with 'A'. There are better hammers for this nail, as seen above.